# How can I define a route for a component with Next js?

Tags: next.js, navigation

On my Next.js version 14 app, I have a `page.tsx` file on my app/tasks folder. On that page I have a button that opens a Dialog/Pop-up to edit a task:
[image]

How can I change the route to `tasks/edit` when opening the edit Dialog component ?

This is my app folder structure so far:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change the route to /tasks/edit when opening the edit Dialog component in your Next.js version 14 app, you can use the useRouter hook provided by Next.js.

In your page.tsx file, you can do something like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const YourPageComponent = () => {
const router = useRouter();

const handleEditButtonClick = () => {
// edit button cicked: Navigate to the edit route 
router.push('/tasks/edit');
};

return (
  <div>
    {/* Your content */}
    <button onClick={handleEditButtonClick}>Edit Task</button>
   {/*content other components */}
 </div>
);
};

export default YourPageComponent;
```

This code snippet assumes that your page.tsx file is located in the tasks folder and is responsible for rendering the page where the edit button is present. Adjust the paths and logic according to your specific requirements.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I am using `import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";` and onClick button I open the modal and `router.push("/tasks/create");` but I am getting the following error: ` http://localhost:3001/tasks/create 404 (Not Found)`. I edited the image of my project folder structure in case you would like to check it.

Comment: the /tasks/create route in your Next.js is configured correctly, right? you'll get a 404 error because Next.js won't recognize the route. sure that you have a create.tsx (or create.js) file inside the pages/tasks directory? also check /tasks/create is a dynamic route (e.g., /tasks/[taskId]/create), and ensurre you're passing the necessary parameters to the route, or adjust the route path accordingly. check for the typos as well.

Comment: I didn't have the /tasks/create route configured correctly. Thanks for your help!